# React Child Component Loop not redenring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Well I have one of the views from my single page application that is a Quiz, But when a click to generate the Components through a loop based on information on my array state he doesn't render it. I'm using react-router in the index.js  maybe this information can help.

Gabarito.js

```
 return(
      <div>
    <h1 className="display-1">Resposta-#{this.props.chave}- 
     {this.props.alternativa}</h1>
    </div>);
```

Quiz

```
state = {       
    respostas:[10],
    gabarito:['Verdadeiro','Falso','Falso','Verdadeiro','Verdadeiro','Falso','Verdadeiro','Falso','Verdadeiro','Verdadeiro'],
    correcao:[],
    novogabarito: this.eachcomponent


  }
  alterarevento = (evento,index) =>{
      let array = this.state.respostas;
      array[index] = evento.target.value;
      this.setState({respostas:array}); 
      console.log(this.state.respostas[index])

  }
  gerargabarito = () =>{
    for(let n=0;n<10;n++){
        if(this.state.respostas[n]===this.state.gabarito[n]){
            this.state.correcao.push('Certa');
        }
        else{
           this.state.correcao.push('Errada');
        }
    }
    console.log(this.state.correcao);
  }
  eachcomponent = () =>{
    return(this.state.correcao.map(resposta=><Gabarito chave={this.state.correcao.indexOf(resposta)} alternativa={resposta}/>));

  }
```

Render of  function

```
<div className="row justify-content-center">
                <span id="teste">{this.state.novogabarito}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
     );
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am overlooking something...but it does not look like you are ever invoking your `alterarevento` and `gerargabarito` functions. So when you call your `eachcomponent` your **correcao array** in your state is still empty so you are not mapping anything.

Before your return statement in your `eachcomponent` function, try logging `correcao` to the console to see if it is empty.

*A word of caution*: you should never manipulate your state directly. So, your `this.state.correcao.push('Certa');`

line should be:

`this.setState({ correcao: [...this.state.correcao, 'Certa'] });`